# NbClust - How to remove one index only from NbClust in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am using the function `NbClust` to define the best number of clusters according to the majority rule, and to determine the best partition. I am using an unbalanced panel and I am applying the function year by year.
For some years (I can hardly indentify them because they are not always the same, I do not know why) the function returns the following error

```
Error in if ((resCritical[ncB - min_nc + 1, 3] >= alphaBeale) && (!foundBeale)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Since the error is related to the `Beale` index, I would like to remove it from the indices that `NbClust` computes. However, the function allows to either do all indices or do just one. Alternatively I should do a loop doing all indices but the `Beale` one, but this is not very efficient.
Any suggestion on

1. how to modify the function to exclude one specific index
2. the interpretation of the error

would be very appreciated.

As a reproducible (hopfully) example, this is the dataframe for year 2004 on which hierarchical clustering with complete linkage gives the above error.

Dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(x= c(0.0130783841691594, 0.0811796289534658, 
0.0270475823858084, 0.0871712792530475, 0.0265691710106049, 0.0382829923183554, 
0.0358792264229904, 0.0369710074848561, 0.0968678748440389, 0.0280162961677389, 
0.0641060604744847, 0.096750772588868), 
y = c(0.290726734324551, 
0.662213464257301, 0.604778245212102, 0.649112827666588, 0.336837686614598, 
0.21960628048058, 0.825429900340104, 0.22066877898435, 0.189433188407458, 
0.452489397011509, 0.45434949089379, 1.16414485174389)), 
row.names = c("BOL", 
"BRA", "COL", "CRI", "ECU", "JAM", "MEX", "PAN", "PER", "PRY", 
"URY", "USA"), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Clustering:

```
NbClust(data = df, distance = "euclidean", method = "complete", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 6)
```